# Google Sheets Script Clear cell on Sheet A after value submitted via form to Sheet B

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

NOTICE - I am a bit of a noob when it comes to writing scripts.  I do lots of google searching, cutting, pasting, modification, researching etc.  I haven't been able to find what I need for this dilemma though I feel it should be easy enough.

**Brief**

I need a particular cell cleared in Sheet A (MaintenanceLogs) after form data is submitted to Sheet B (ClearMaintenanceFlag).

Sheet B contains the lookup data in column B which I want to do a lookup on Sheet A column B and clear cell on corresponding row on F in sheet A.

**End User Process**

Users submit maintenance logs via a form (Sheet A) and when they do routine maintenance if they find something which requires followup they tick a box on the form which returns a "Yes" in column F.  Column B of the maintenance logs contains a UniqueID generated when they submit their maintenance log.

When they correct the flagged maintenance they submit the UniqueID via the form which creates a log to say the flagged item has been corrected.  We want to then remove the "flag" from the maintenance log.

**My Understanding**

As stated, I'm a bit of a script novice.  I can do an obvious Lookup function to search for said ID and return the data from the flag column but piecing it all together in an automated script.........I'm a bit lost.

I think I need to have an onChange event?? or onSubmit?  I just don't know the syntax to pull it off.  I've done lots of reading but it's a lot for a noob to piece together.  Happy to pay to get it working.

**End Result**

At the end, we want the "flag" to disappear from the maintenance log.  I am using filters etc to create filtered lists which show maintenance items still going so when the flag goes, my list updates.

Trust that makes sense.  If someone could point me in the right direction that would be AMAZING.

Comment: Welcome. Please follow the [tour], read [ask] and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers. Tip: Include a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view only to make easier to visualize the spreadsheet structure. It's worthy to mention that on this site questions should not include personal introductions but you could include that in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update the maintenance log on Sheet A to remove the follow-up flag when a form response is received on Sheet B.

- Install the following script
- Update the sheet names as required
- Create an Installable trigger "onformsubmit"

The script  get the Unique ID from the "post followup" form and searches for that value in Column B of Sheet A. It uses the `indexOf` method [Doc Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to find the match. `indexOf` returns the first index at which the ID is found, or -1 if it is not present. It's worth noting that the result generated by 'indexOf' is zero-based.

The index is the row reference, and since the flag is in the adjacent column, it is easy to update the value.

Personally, I would not be entirely comfortable updating the actual response sheet. It is too easy to update the sheet from the form, and all the changes would be lost. I would prefer to maintain a running copy of the Sheet A response sheet, and use the copy for all my reporting as well as making the "followup flag" changes. More experienced users *might* (or not) regard this approach as unnecessarily conservative.

---

```
function wa141633(e) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // identify and reference sheet names
  var logsheetname = "Form Responses 2"; //(SheetA)
  var updatesheetname = "Form Responses 3"; //(Sheet B)
  var logsheet = ss.getSheetByName(logsheetname);
  var updatesheet = ss.getSheetByName(updatesheetname);

  // display the event obects
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); // DEBUG

  // get the sheet for the response
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet().getSheetName();

  // only interested if the sheet is for the update sheet/Sheet B
  if (sheet != logsheetname){

    // get the Unique ID
    // Substitute "FollowupCode for your question name"
    // the response is a string, so convert it to an integer
    var respvalue = e.namedValues['FollowupCode'][0];
    var ID = parseInt(respvalue, 10);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the ID  = "+ID)

    // get data from sheet A
    var logLR = logsheet.getLastRow();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row on sheet A = "+logLR);
    var logRange = logsheet.getRange(2, 2, logLR-1,2);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the log range = "+logRange.getA1Notation());
    var logValue = logRange.getValues();

    // just get the first column (Column B)
    var uniqueIDs = logValue.map(function(e){return e[0];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]
    // Logger.log(uniqueIDs); // DEBUG

    // search for the ID in the array of UniqueIDs
    // indexOf will return the row index of the ID
    // if the ID is not found, it will return -1.
    var result = uniqueIDs.indexOf(ID);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: result = "+result)

    if (result !=-1){

      var flag = logValue[result][1];
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the flag is "+flag);
      // change the flag value
      logValue[result][1] = "No";
      //update the values
      logRange.setValues(logValue);
    }
  }
}
```